# Can't find named elements

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Something is not clicking for me with this code:

```
var cfgDoc = XElement.Load(_cfgFile);
foreach (var x in cfgDoc.Elements("property"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

I am expecting to be able to output only nodes that are named `property`, but getting zilch. If I leave the XName parameter out, I get the document (below), which shows at least it is being loaded correctly.

What am I missing?

```xml
<session-factory xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <property name="connection.release_mode">on_close</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
</session-factory>
```

**2nd try**

```
var cfgDoc = XElement.Load(_cfgFile);
XNamespace ns = "urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2"; 
var properties = cfgDoc.Elements(ns + "property");
Assert.That(properties.Count() > 0);
foreach (var x in cfgDoc.Elements(ns + "property")) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One (or both) of these might do it:

```
cfgDoc.Descendants(ns + "property")
```

and

```
var cfgDoc = XDocument.Load(_cfgFile).Root;
```

(Jon's right too, you'll definitely need the namespace)

Comment: I was going to suggest this, so I'll explain why these would make a difference.  When you do just XElement.Load, the variable returned represents the root node, which is distinct from the root element.  In your example file, `session-factory` is the root element.  The root node is an abstract concept representing the entirety of the document, and is considered the parent of the root (`session-factory`) element.  To get from the root node to the `property` elements, you have to get through `session-factory` first.

Comment: Well, Root does work too, but only with Descendents as far as I can see. Close enough to be the answer to what I asked tho! Cheers

Answer (score 4):

You haven't provided the namespace which is effectively inherited by the child elements. Try this:

```
var cfgDoc = XElement.Load(_cfgFile);
XNamespace ns = "urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2";
foreach (var x in cfgDoc.Elements(ns + "property"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Comment: Hi Jon. Sounds logical, but same result - zilch (I tacked on the code to the end of my post).

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're loading the file/xml? Check your `_cfgFile` value. Your 2nd try works for me:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace XElementMadness
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var xml = "<session-factory xmlns=\"urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2\"><property name=\"connection.release_mode\">on_close</property><property name=\"show_sql\">true</property></session-factory>";

            var cfgDoc = XElement.Load(new StringReader(xml));
            XNamespace ns = "urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2";
            var properties = cfgDoc.Elements(ns + "property");

            foreach (var x in cfgDoc.Elements(ns + "property"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

which outputs:

```
<property name="connection.release_mode" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2 ">on_close</property> <property name="show_sql" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">true</property>
```

Comment: Aaron. My _cfgFile is a path to an xml file, which I guess from the results is handled differently than constructing it how you did in your snippet. Probably related to what Simon's comment is saying. Cheers